# How to run RocksDB service on Ubuntu for performance testing?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, performance-testing, rocksdb

I'm trying to test the performance of RocksDB. I installed both DB-Bench for performance testing and also RocksDB. I have no idea how I can start RocksDB service on Ubuntu and run the performance benchmark using db-bench. Any help/advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

RocksDB is not an application, it is built into the application as a library. I think RocksDB ships with a simple demonstrator called rdb, but they also include tools for benchmarking, for which they primarily suggest you use [db_bench](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Benchmarking-tools). That will give you information about how fast RocksDB is on your system as compared to others, but in the end the performance will greatly depend on how you use it in your application.